# Multiple Gnuplots within figure giving incorrect colors

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot 3 data sets, each a different color, on one plot, but my code coloring seems to always incorrecty assign the last set's color also to the middle set:

```
set terminal png
set datafile separator ","

set title "Hours slept"
set xlabel "Date"
set ylabel "Hours"
set output '1.png'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%y"
set xrange ["09/17/22":"11/12/22"]
set format x "%m/%d"
set style line 1 lt 1 linecolor rgb "blue" lw 2 pt 1
set style line 2 lt 2 linecolor rgb "red" lw 2 pt 1
set style line 3 lt 3 linecolor rgb "yellow" lw 2 pt 1

plot "< grep -e '\*' fraction.csv | sed 's/*//'" using 1:($4) title 'weekends' ls 1 with points, \
"< grep -e '^[0-9]' fraction.csv" using 1:($4) title 'weekdays' ls 2 with points, \
"< grep -e '\^' fraction.csv | sed 's/^//'" using 1:($4) title 'fridays' ls 3 with points
```

[image]

There are suddenly no reds (the middle plot).
When I remove *just* the 3rd friday plot (last line), it looks like this:
[image]

So clearly I'm doing the coloring wrong? With three plots, all the weekdays become yellow  instead of red.

This weird bug is driving me crazy. I initially did it like this without the explicit styles:

```
"< grep -e '^[0-9]' fraction.csv" using ($1):($3) title 'weekends' with points lc rgb 'blue'
```

And the same exact problem happened.
When I run each of the 3 grep calls they are all distinct data sets and there are far more weekday points than the other two.

Comment: Please show some examples data lines from your file `fraction.csv`! First it looks like that your date is in column 1 and data in column 4, later you use column 3. Please clarify!

Comment: Problem solved? Please show some example data!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your data, so, the following script creates some random test data.
Why do you use `grep` and `sed` if you can do it with gnuplot only?
Check `help tm_wday` which returns a number for the weekdays (0-6) for Sunday to Saturday. Define a function which sets the color accordingly.
For the legend you can use `keyentry` (check `help keyentry`).

**Addition:** more explanations

I didn't have an clue about your gnuplot level, I thought you could adapt the example to your case.
Well, there is for almost every command, function, keyword a help entry in gnuplot. In the gnuplot console type `help <keyword>`.

- `myColor(t) = ...`, defines a function using the ternary operator which returns a color in the format `0xRRGGBB` depending on the weekday, check `help ternary`, `help tm_wday`, `help colorspec`.
- `set format x "%m/%d" timedate` will format the x-axis as time axis, check `help time_specifiers`.
- `...(t=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt))...` in gnuplot date/time is handled as seconds passed since`1970-01-01 00:00:00`, check `help timecolumn`.
- `...lc rgb var`, sets the color from the data (or function), check `help lc variable`.
- list your weekday categories in a string and address them by index via `word` check `help word`.
- for the keyentry use a loop (check `help for` and `help keyentry`) and get the color from the weekday number. `1970-01-01` was a Thursday (=4). So, subtract 24*3600 seconds (=1 day) in order to get from the indices 1,2,3 to the weekday numbers 4,5,6 (Thu,Fri,Sat) (=weekdays, fridays, weekends) which will return the colors (red, yellow, blue).

Ok, so I modified the code such that you just have to

1. skip the random data creation section
2. replace `$Data` with `'<YourFilename>'`, i.e. in your case `'fraction.csv'`.

**Script:**

```
### color days of the week differently
reset session

myTimeFmt = "%m/%d/%y"

# create some random test data
set table $Data separator comma
    t0 = time(0)
    plot '+' u (strftime(myTimeFmt,t0+$0*24*3600)):(invnorm(rand(0))+7) w table
unset table

set datafile separator comma
set key noautotitle
set yrange[0:12]
set format x "%m/%d" timedate
myColor(t) = (d=tm_wday(t), d==5 ? 0xffff00 : d==6 || d==0 ? 0x0000ff : 0xff0000)
myDay(i)   = word("weekdays fridays weekends",i)

plot $Data u (t=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2:(myColor(t)) w p pt 13 lc rgb var, \
     for [i=1:3] keyentry w p pt 13 lc rgb myColor((i-1)*24*3600) ti myDay(i)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have absolutely no clue how the code works, let alone how to take inputs from a csv (date in column 1). I changed it to 
plot "< cat 1.csv" u 1:4:(myColor(t=1)) w p pt 13 lc rgb var, \
     for [i=4:6] keyentry w p pt 13 lc rgb myColor((i+3)*24*3600) ti myDay(i-3)
but setting (t=1): before 'u' causes undefined y error and setting myColor(t=1) makes everything red. 

Is there really no way to just get my naive 3 plot color to color each plot correctly? It seems a much quicker fix, albiet in the short run.

Comment: @GraceSawyer see modified answer with explanations. Please show an example of your data. If your data is in column 4, you have to change the column in the above script accordingly.